# Selecting Records From two tables with many to many relationship

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables user and rights.I want to fetch each user with its assigned right as I attached the screen shot of tables plus result I want.FYI I use PostgreSQL.
Any solution is highly appreciated.
Thanks In advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.uid, u.login, STRING_AGG(r.code, ',') code
FROM UserTable u
/* LEFT */ JOIN Rights r ON u.uid = r.uid
GROUP BY u.uid, u.login
```

Comment: ThANKS i did string_agg and array_agg but it is not working maybe the array size is limit.

Comment: @ali *but it is not working* Function **CANNOT** not to work if it exists. If exists, it works always, producing either a result or an error message. You do not obtain the result? You must to obtain the error message and to add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add **::varchar(200)** near string_agg

```
SELECT u.uid, u.login, STRING_AGG(r.code, ',')::varchar(200) code 
FROM UserTable u 
JOIN Rights r 
    ON u.uid = r.uid 
GROUP BY u.uid, u.login
```